# How to conver xml value into Object

Tags: javascript, xml, object, extjs

I have one xml value which is like this.

```
<AB 
AA="10" BB="20" C="30" FLG="40" F="50" START="60"
</AB>
```

How to store this into object.

Output Example : `var obj = {AA:"10" BB:"20" C:"30" FLG:"40" F:"50" START:"60"}`

Comment: https://davidwalsh.name/convert-xml-json

Answer (score 0):

For current example regexp ill be easier.

regexp - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

or you can use for more complex xmls

DOMParser - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Parsing_and_serializing_XML

Answer (score 0):

You can use window.DOMParser() on most recent browsers:

```
var str = '<AB AA="10" BB="20" C="30" FLG="40" F="50" START="60"></AB>',
    parser, xml, attrib, obj = {};

if(window.DOMParser) {
  parser = new DOMParser();
  xml = parser.parseFromString(str, "text/xml");
  attrib = xml.documentElement.attributes;

  for(var i = 0; i < attrib.length; i++) {
    obj[attrib.item(i).name] = attrib.item(i).value;
  }
  console.log(obj);
}
```

Output:

```
Object { AA="10",  BB="20",  C="30",  ...}
```

Note that this is just a simple example with a single element, but the same principles would apply to a more complex structure.